# Multiple apps in one project or one project per app in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I have, at the moment 2 android apps in which I want to add notifications and maybe ads and analytics, using Firebase, since it's free and easy to implement.

I see that I have 2 options:

1. Create a new project with my company's name and add the 2 apps in there
2. Create 2 projects, each with app's name and on each of them add the related apps.

Which one would be the correct approach and why?
Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Don't mean to be flippant, but the answer is "it depends" :-)

A canonical way of setting up a Firebase project is to have it correspond to a "logical app", and create separate Firebase apps for the Android or iOS or web versions.

I'd not personally put a grab bag of unrelated apps into the same Firebase project, but your mileage may vary.

Depending on what you want to do, it *might* make sense to group related (but logically different apps) under the same Firebase project. But note that that has implications on how your apps would interact with the Firebase features.

For example, all apps in the same Firebase project would share the same logical Firebase database instance (with the same hostname / end-point).

You would probably want to go through the various features that you plan to use and make sure that the organizational structure satisfies the way you plan to use the platform features.

Comment: still, how would one achieve such setup ?

Comment: can we integrate the two ways?

Comment: if the setup would be "multiple apps" in one "project": Are we able to aggregate the events only for specific app ? I mean is the apps name a new dimension when analyzing the data ?