# Can you have more than one iOS application utilizing the same Firebase back end?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I already have an app out with Apple that uses a specific bundle id and Firebase realtime DB for its back end.

Now instead of creating a new Firebase realtime DB project, I wish to use the same project; main reason being is that there will be information in the existing Firebase project that I will also require in the new application, as well as this should/wouild allow users to login to either app with the same credentials.

Now I want to create a NEW iOS bundle identifier id so that the app is separately purchased from the itunes store but access the same Firebase realtime DB data.... is that possible/allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add 30 apps to a single project to share data, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more#best-practices).

> Firebase restricts the total number of Firebase Apps within a Firebase project to 30.

See also:

- [Multiple apps in one project or one project per app in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326354/multiple-apps-in-one-project-or-one-project-per-app-in-firebase)
- [Pros and cons of using one project for multiple apps in Firebase Could Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976463/pros-and-cons-of-using-one-project-for-multiple-apps-in-firebase-could-messaging)
- [Adding multiple apps in a firebase project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52115298/adding-multiple-apps-in-a-firebase-project)
- [Add multiple apps to single project in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918153/add-multiple-apps-to-single-project-in-firebase)
- [Is there a way to have 1 Firebase database for 2 apps with different package names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390095/is-there-a-way-to-have-1-firebase-database-for-2-apps-with-different-package-nam)
- https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/VAtoKx6qJjw